# Once upon a tile in Hollywood

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, lateral-thinking

Bon Venndredi,

the three overlapping ellipses create seven disjoint regions.  Each ellipse represents an as yet unknown category.  Your job is to place the tiles in the regions and deduce the categories.  One is already placed for you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three sets are

> A: Strings that can prefix BOAT

> B: Movies ending GIRLS

> C: Strings that can prefix TIME

Thus

> $A\,\cap\,B\;\cap\,C=\text{SHOW}$ (or possibly $\text{DREAM}$)

> $A\,\cap\,B\;\cap\;!C=\text{DREAM}$ (or possibly $\text{SHOW}$)

> $A\,\cap\;!B\,\cap\,C=\text{LIFE}$

> $!A\,\cap\,B\,\cap\,C=\text{MEAN}$

> $A\,\cap\;!B\;\cap\;!C=\text{SPEED}$

> $!A\,\cap\,B\;\cap\;!C=\text{KISS THE}$

> $!A\,\cap\;!B\,\cap\,C=\text{PAS}$

If anyone with better graphics skills than I can make this answer prettier, please do so.